# No line found error, with additional inputs

Tags: java, console, command-line-arguments

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

Though the code works till the print statement for a.name is executed but it *throws the error as soon as the `object b` is created*.

I have given more inputs than required, considering that the error is demanding an input.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class jatt{ 
    String name;
    String DOB;
    String BG;
    int BP;
    int TeleNumber;
    int DrivNumber;
    String address;

    void getdata(){
        Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
        name=in.nextLine();
        DOB=in.nextLine();
        BG=in.nextLine();
        BP=in.nextInt();
        TeleNumber=in.nextInt();
        DrivNumber=in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        address=in.nextLine();
    }
    jatt(){
        getdata();
    }
    jatt(String name, String DOB ,String BG, int BP, int TeleNumber, int DrivNumber, String address){
        this.name=name;
        this.DOB=DOB;
        this.BG=BG;
        this.BP=BP;
        this.TeleNumber=TeleNumber;
        this.DrivNumber=DrivNumber;
        this.address=address;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
        jatt a= new jatt();
        System.out.println(a.name);
        jatt b= new jatt();
        System.out.println(b.name);
    }
}
```

The error comes only when the second object is created, the code works fine for a single object. And I know about the problem of using in.nextLine() just after in.nextInt(). So the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Add `in.nextLine()` after `DrivNumber=in.nextInt();`

Comment: making a variable static never restricts a user to call it through an object with the `.` notitifier, though its a bad practice.

Comment: Sir I know about the in.nextLine(); but the code does not work even after using that

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this problem. After the addition of `in.nextLine()` after `DrivNumber=in.nextInt();`, it works correctly as far as I can see.